# How do I specify multiple range restrictions?

Tags: python

I would like to specify range restrictions for multiple variables in Python code.

I have tried troubleshooting on pythontutor.com to no success.

```
for i in range (0,5), j in range (1,2):
    d=(abs(a[i]-(c+j)/(s+1)))
    z.append(d)
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

Comment: nested for loops, perhaps?

Comment: @PedroHenrique, I don't think that's the right dupe target.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a nested `for` loop:

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

Otherwise you might want `zip()`:

```
for i, j in zip(range(2), range(2)):
    print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 1
```